# Good way to prevent grease build up in kitchen?

Tags: equipment, cleaning

My kitchen items end up getting a sticky grease coating when I cook regularly. Things not even near the stove top. I don't have an overhead fan, what can I do about this?

Comment: Use less fat, clean regularly? Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Honestly: get  yourself a range hood. If you cook regularly, you want some proper equipment, don't you?

Answer (score 6):

If a dishwasher is present, get dishwasher-safe boxes with a lid on them, and store less frequently used items in these boxes. Whenever doing a "deep clean" of your kitchen, put the boxes in the dishwasher while sorting out the contents.

Answer (score 6):

A cooker/range hood. The proper sort will suck in all that greasy fumes, pass them through a carbon filter (which needs changing) and vents it outside, or upwards(in smaller kitchens without a place to vent it. Its also helpful if you're cooking something that may have irritating fumes.

There's pretty much nothing that will mitigate the problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

I guess cleaning them up is the best. I always clean my work station immediately after cooking, be it deep-frying or just stir-frying because oil spatter that easily.

Do not assume that you could clean them up later, or maybe after a few rounds of cooking because they will stick and harden. Soon enough, it would be difficult to clean.

But if there's a case where your grease build up isn't that bad, using coke with lemon does the job because of the level of acidity in the 2.

Answer (score 2):

Use less fat and a lower temperature.   [Can also use grease a screen.](https://www.google.com/#q=grease+screen+cooking)

Grease will vaporize and then condense on walls / surfaces.  Without a fan that is going to happen.

Can also bake or crock or ....

Answer (score 1):

Use methods other than frying to cook your food.
Seriously put a lid on your pan, use lower temperatures to cook and use higher temperature oils and fats.  Clean regularly as soon as possible after cooking, old coatings are more difficult to remove

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue -- and I have no range hood, as it's a ~85 year old house, and I'd have to lose or change the upper cabinets to do it.

My only suggestion is to keep things that are annoying to clean in a cabinet when you're frying, and then clean the cabinets afterwards.  If you don't have a good storage place, you can cover them with a plastic bag.

You might be able to coat the cabinets in something -- tape up a dropcloth or similar so it's not exposed.

... unfortunately, I have a pot rack above my stove, and hooks with utensils right behind it ... so they're not really in a good position to protect them without taking it all down.  (and cleaning the pot rack sucks, as some of the hooks on the potrack can't be removed w/out disassembling)

Answer (score 0):

Some times I cook splattering foods and I lay a kitchen towel over things I want to protect. I have started doing bacon in the oven and seldom fry anything but eggs.  But if you try covering things until At least after doing the dishes, it helps

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a solution after degreasing everything with vinegar first then create a baking soda paste to further remove any stubborn build up once everything is clean and dry take a napkin/paper towels moisten with a little mineral oil and wipe everything it won’t stop the issue but it makes it less of a pain to clean later prevents that grease buildup from becoming stuck on. Hope that helps also hope I reiterated the steps properly. I seen this on YouTube a kitchen cleaning hacks video.